# RailsGem setup leading to undefined errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The following setup is generating `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`  and subsequent multiple `TypeError: $ is undefined` errors, thus leading to scripts not firing.

Gemfile calls

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete'
```

which translated into the Gemfile.lock to

```
jquery-rails (4.3.5)
  rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
  railties (>= 4.2.0)
  thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
  railties (>= 3.2.16)
```

while `application.js` is defined with

```
// require jquery3
// require jquery-ujs
// require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
// require jquery.Jcrop
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require foundation
//= require rails.validations
```

Thus, elements like

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[

$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {  [...]
```

and

```
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
```

do not fire, as a consequence of `TypeError: $ is undefined` .

Another rails 5.2 application is defined in the same manner and does not generate such errors. What is wrong with this set-up (or what am I missing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application.html.erb, do you have this line ?

**application.html.erb**

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': true %>
```

And try to write in your application.js in this way (maybe you forgot equal before jquery)

```
//= require jquery
```

Comment: the application file has `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`  Good pickup on the equals sign, it was missing!

Answer (score 0):

In rails application

jQuery is not included by default. Let's add it on the Gemfile.

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

The jquery-rails gem contains the jQuery files. Install the gem with

```
bundle install
```

To include the jQuery files in our application
will require a few files on app/assets/javascripts/application.js

You need to remove rails-ujs since you're using jquery_ujs for the same purpose.

```
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

on your file.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("All working fine");
})
```

Or include file.js before use it on page.

Comment: in the question, it is clearly stated that jquery is declared in the Gemfile and `.lock`has it installed...  That is not the issue; the missing equals sign was.

Comment: Ok got your configuration problem. you forgot equal before jquery3. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this , what i did was remove turbolinks . If this works , then there is an issue with how you are loading the libraries in incorrect order .

```
// require jquery3
// require jquery-ujs
// require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
// require jquery.Jcrop
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require activestorage
//= require foundation
//= require rails.validations
```